# Building a library using Spring Boot: Unable to find @SpringBootConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am currently working on Microservices and this project is basically a library and **it does not have a main function.** I am writing Unit test cases for this library, but I am getting unable to find @SpringBootConfiguration. If there is no main function, can't we execute the Unit test cases ?

**The only file in the library**

```
class OnlyFile {

    void validate(){

    }

}
```

**Testing**

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyTest {

     @Test
     void testIt(){
        //
        //
      }
     
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write and run unit tests and it is only a library, then I don't think it is neccesary for you to have @SpringBootTest annotation on your test class. It is used for integration testing, when you need to have a spring application context in your integration test.

When running integration tests in a class annotated with @SpringBootTest, then you need to have a class in same package or subpackage as the test class annotated with @SpringBootConfiguration, which contains the configuration to load the application context. The class could be empty if you don't need to customize the configuration. Alternatively, you can specify which components to use when loading the application context like this

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ...)
```